# Reading first X characters of a line to a string

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a file that is formatted like this:

```
Word1          num1 num2
Word2 Word3    num3 num4
```

between Word1 and num1 there are 15 spaces, which are used by words like Word1, Word2 and Word3.

I want to read the first 15 characters and put them into a string, then read the numbers:

```
string[0] = "Word1          ";
number[0] = num1;
number[1] = num2;
string[1] = "Word2 Word3    ";
number[2] = num3;
number[3] = num4;
...
```

The function i currently use to read the data from the file:

```
void read_data(){

ifstream datafile("U2.txt");

datafile>> product_count >> product2_count;

for (int i = 1; i <= product_count; i++) {
    datafile>> product_cost[i];
}

for (int i = 1; i <= product2_count; i++) {
    datafile>> products[i].product2_name;
    for (int j = 1; j <= product_count; j++) {
        datafile>> products[i].product_ammount[j];
    }
}

datafile.close();

}
```

and the data file itself:

```
6 5
12 25 35 2 3 9
Salotos        5 1 0 0 2 1
Kepsnys        6 3 12 9 0 0
Gaiva          0 0 1 15 1 0
Ledai Miau     0 0 5 5 5 1
Tortas         1 2 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: And what you've tried so far?

Comment: so far, I'm just reading a word at a time, but that wont work for me, because if there is a string made out of 2 or more words, it reads the 1st word into a string and then the rest to the upcoming ints, not the same string, so where the ints were supposed to be, they return 0. Basically like "inFile >> string >> number >> number"

Comment: If actually you show us the code that would be better :)

Comment: Can you translate the identifiers to english, please?

Comment: *pr_kaina* not defined, and also how's the files formatted? With spaces, tabs...?

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the code for you, but basic idea is to

- read a line with `getline()` to a `std::string`
- take first 15 chars, trim them to remove space
- build a `std::stringstream` with the rest of the string, and do `sstream >> num1[i] >> num2[i]` (where `numX` are arrays of int, and `i` the index of line.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the line

```
datafile >> products[i].product2_name;
```

that only reads up to the first space. You need to read it like CharlesB suggests with extracting the first 15 chars using `string::substr`, then trimming. [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/trim/)

I strongly suspect your `for` loops should be starting from 0 and not 1.